# parser for Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, bytestring

Hi
i'm facing the following problem, i have to re-write an existant code to improve his performances. the old version was using a parser defined like this :

```
newtype Parser Char a = Parser {runParser :: [Char] -> [(a,[Char])]}
```

to parse lines from files. but it was too slow and required a lot of memory to achieve the computation upon lines. To improve that code, I decided to use Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 instead of String, but i don't know how to deal with the parser, is it possible to defined a parser in this way ?

```
newtype Parser Char a = parser {runParser :: ByteString -> [(a,ByteString)]} ?
```

or, is there any parser package dedicate to these kind of work ?

thanks to reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.8.1.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-Lazy.html) and [Parsec 3](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.1/doc/html/Text-Parsec-ByteString-Lazy.html) both have interfaces targeting lazy ByteStrings.

(And of course, it is possible to define a parser in that way, but I think you mean

```
newtype Parser a = Parser {runParser :: ByteString -> [(a,ByteString)]}
```

)